# Is there dcc32.exe in RAD Studio XE2? Error: This version of the product does not support command line compiling

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, dcc32

Is there dcc32.exe in RAD Studio XE2? When run get error:

> This version of the product does not support command line compiling.

Comment: Are you using a trial version? If so this is as intended. See https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=276895#276895

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither the trial version, nor the Starter edition include command-line compiler.

[Delphi XE2 Feature Matrix](http://www.embarcadero.com/images/dm/products/Delphi_XE2_Feature_Matrix.pdf)

Comment: @arbautjc That was an invalid edit, the link referes to XE2 not 3

Answer (score 1):

This is your trial version or Starter edition of IDE...compiler doesn't support command-line compiling when you're using those versions.